Why doesn't Philip directly answer Jesus' query in John 6:5-7?
We read in John 6:5-7 (KJV):

When Jesus then lifted up his eyes, and saw a great company come unto him, he saith unto Philip, Whence shall we buy bread, that these may eat? And this he said to prove him: for he himself knew what he would do.
Philip answered him, Two hundred pennyworth of bread is not sufficient for them, that every one of them may take a little.

Curiously enough, Philip is not directly answering the question of Jesus. He should have answered that there are such-and-such bakers in the town nearby, but it is doubtful that they could deliver the required quantity. Instead, Philip is referring to the financial implication of such a free distribution of food to thousands of people.
Why doesn't Philip directly answer Jesus' query?

Note that "pennyworth" in the KJV is denarii in the Greek text, a laborer's wage for a day.

Yes, Dieter. Many versions use the word denarii. Read with the Parable of the Labourers, bread worth 200 denarii is a huge quantity which no baker stores at a time.

Given that 200 denarii was 200 days wages, that’s a little over half a year’s salary for a laborer. If we assume $53k/year today in USD (from zip recruiter as average blue collar salary), that’d be almost $30k! While this is a crude guess, it helps us see that it’s a lot of money and Philip is saying that even that much money wouldn’t be close to sufficient.

In the US today at least, the likely 20k+ people could easily run into the hundreds of thousands of USD today to feed a meal, so $30k would be wildly insufficient. Obviously from Philip’s response the situation was similar back then.

It's very normal in human communication not to literally answer a person's question, but to understand the implication of the question, and answer in such a way as to address it. E.g. a son walks in the door an hour past curfew. Father: "Do you know what time it is?" Implication: "You're very late. Why?" If the son said "Yes," that would be a "direct" answer, but so far from addressing the implication of the father's question that it could be considered rude. More likely reply from the son: "I had a flat tire." Implication: Dealing with the tire delayed my return home.

Why, please? To me it's not at all clear whether the Question is Biblical or Linguistic.

You will notice something in John 6:5-7:

5 Then Jesus lifted up His eyes, and seeing a great multitude coming
toward Him, He said to Philip, “Where shall we buy bread, that these
may eat?” 6 But this He said to test him, for He Himself knew what He
would do.
7 Philip answered Him, “Two hundred denarii worth of bread is not
sufficient for them, that every one of them may have a little.”


We see that Jesus was testing Philip.
1. A lack of faith.

Despite Jesus' power, John 6:6 notes that Jesus questions Philip "only
to test him." The purpose of such a test could be for the reason of
showing Philip where he stands in his faith, or perhaps for Jesus to
lead Philip toward a greater understanding of His power. [1]

By focusing on the financial aspect rather than answering Jesus directly, Philip might have revealed his limited understanding of Jesus’s ability to provide in a supernatural way.
2. Philip's response displayed the magnitude of the miracle to follow.

*Philip answered, Two hundred pennyworth of bread is not sufficient,
&c. — The Roman denarius, or penny, being equal to about seven pence
half- penny of English money, two hundred of them were equal to
about six pounds five shillings sterling, as much, probably, as
their whole stock amounted to. [2]

By pointing out the cost, Philip is showing Jesus the impossibility of the task from a human perspective, which makes the subsequent miracle of feeding the multitude with just five loaves and two fish even more absolutely astonishing.
3. Philip was just giving Jesus a realistic assessment.
Philip was perhaps being practical. He might be giving Jesus a realistic assessment of the situation. This would make sense as this could be seen as an attempt to express the sheer scale of the logistical and financial challenge that feeding such a large crowd would entail. I mean, why tell Jesus where the bakers are if they didn't have the necessary amount of money in the first place?




References:




1
Biblical Studies/New Testament Commentaries/The Gospel of John/Chapter 6 - Wikibooks, open books for an open world. (n.d.). https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Biblical_Studies/New_Testament_Commentaries/The_Gospel_of_John/Chapter_6


2
John 6 Benson commentary. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/benson/john/6.htm




I think this is correct.  The key is the word πειράζω (to cause truth or falsehood to be evident).  The idea is Philip makes simple, very quick, and very accurate assessments of a situation.  He's the one--very early on--who told Nathaniel (a skeptic), "We have found him..." (John 1:45).  So, Jesus knew the assessment he was going to get.  An answer that is basically, "This won't work."  Jesus knew what he was going to do, right?  He was simply setting the stage for the narrative that was going to unfold.  So, he "makes the truth evident" (πειράζω, prove) by asking Philip a question.

To go little further (and to disagree with the WikiBooks reference), I don't think πειράζων (present participle of πειράζω) is a purpose participle.  A much more common way to express purpose would be either εἰς + article + infinitive or ἵνα + subjunctive.  If you want to convey purpose with the participle, you would generally do so with a future participle.  This one is a present tense.  What John says here is, (literally) "He said this, proving out him."  It's a way of introducing Philip's reply as a statement that "rings true".

And one more which relates to Hermeneutics.  The concept of "testing Philip" is not developed further by the narrative.  Why would John bring that up in this narrative and just let it hang there in mid-air (as it were)?  All answers to that question are explanations driven totally by the reader's assumptions.  Even the original hearers of the question and answer would not have thought, "Philip passed the test."  No explanation of why is driven by the text.  So, from a Hermeneutics perspective, such an interpretation is wrong, irrelevant, or at best, weak.

That WAS Philip's direct answer to Jesus' question! It's not up to anyone else to say Philip ought to have answered 'so-and'so,' to be direct. It was an honest answer to a perplexing question Jesus put to his disciples. Philip's answer expressed his perplexity directly arising from the question.
It directly tells all who heard it that he had understood the question at a material level, and that he could not see how he and the other disciples could possibly meet that material requirement. Under the circumstances, it was an understandable answer to what might have seemed to him to be an unreasonable question.
However, the key point is that Jesus was testing the faith of the disciples. And the account should remind all who read it that our own faith is dreadfully prone to waver when we only look at existing circumstances, instead of seeing with the eyes of faith. The disciples should have known that their inability to do something could be dealt with by turning to Christ. An answer of faith would have been along the lines of, "Lord, YOU are the bread of life. Show us what you will do!" That would, indeed, have been the most direct answer possible, but given the lack of faith at that moment, it wasn't going to be given. The only possible answer, given Philip's lack of faith, was the one he gave. So, it was as direct as he could make it.

This is a typical human habit of thinking beyond the question asked and it's based in an element of fear.  Philip was thinking ahead about the cost of purchasing the amount of food necessary to feed so many, instead of answering the actual question Jesus asked.  He was thinking how to do it, rather than just answer the question.  People do this all the time, and it is annoying when someone tries to read the OP's mind about why the question was asked, or the motive behind the question, and imputes a reason that was not intended by the OP.  It is a self-defense mechanism that many people use to deflect or head off possible blame or criticism.
We also do it in reverse by asking an obvious question when we really want to know something else.  Such as "Why did you turn here?" when we really mean "where are you going?"  Our communication skills are not the best and too many times we make assumptions.

38 And he was in the hinder part of the ship, asleep on a pillow: and they awake him, and say unto him, Master, carest thou not that we perish? (Mark 4:38, KJV)

The disciples made an accusation because of their fear, instead of simply asking Jesus to help them. Assumptions create confusion.

Jesus' question in  John 6:5-7 is a rhetorical question that does not need an answer.  In a way, Philip does answer the question by a statement that suggests how impossible the task is.
Thus, Philip correctly replies by offering a supporting statement that the task of feeding about 20,000 people (= 5000 men plus women and children) is beyond human means.  This is the perfect dramatic setup for the ensuing miracle of Jesus - which, of course, is supernatural.

All the previous answers are excellent, so let me just add this thought.
It's also not unreasonable to translate the words in verse 6 as Jesus was teasing or experimenting with Philip. "Experimenting" is a great euphemism for hiding a light touch of mischief (i.e. I don't tease people, I "experiment" with them out of curiosity and interest).
Philip did not answer Jesus' "where" question, but rather introduced the logical precondition of affordability.
Though highly unlikely, what if there existed a Binah's Bakery Bazaar and Warehouse within walking distance? Couldn't Jesus have just as miraculously produced three silver minas (worth 300 denarii) from the mouths of the two fish? This would still have required trust.
As Mike Sangrey noted in his insightful comment (which deserved to be an answer):

The concept of "testing Philip" is not developed further by the
narrative. Why would John bring that up in this narrative and just let
it hang there in mid-air (as it were)? All answers to that question
are explanations driven totally by the reader's assumptions.

This is the key to this interaction in my opinion. Jesus did not return to Philip with any admonition regarding his faith.
Note: I checked BDAG for the semantic range and checked modern Greek for words that mean "tease" to check whether this is even possible, and it is.

First consider that Philip lived in a capitalistic society, not a socialistic one.  Charities might take care of a small number of people, but not such a large number of people.  To feed 5,000 people by human means would take money.
Put the entire context together.  John's purpose was:

Now Jesus did many other signs in the presence of the disciples, which are not written in this book; but these are written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name.
(John 20:30–31, ESV)

Feeding the five thousand was one of the seven signs in chapters 2 - 12.  John chose seven spectacular miracles many that no one other than Jesus had ever done.

Never since the world began has it been heard that anyone opened the eyes of a man born blind.
(John 9:32, ESV)

Philips answer to Jesus' subjunctive question "Where can we buy bread" is realistic.  Philip's answer is essentially told that there was no place because they weren't even close to having enough money.  Then Andrew pointing out the boy's fishes and loves (only enough for the boy) made the miracle even more spectacular.
Given the circumstances wasn't Philip's answer what Jesus expected? It served the purpose of pointing out the spectacular nature of the sign that lead into the Bread of Life discourse.

They're on the other shore of the Sea of Galilee, across from Philip's hometown of Bethsaida. Something like 15km distance. He isn't necessarily a fisherman, as Simon and Andrew are elsewhere described to be. So we don't know how well he knew the area.
"Test him" (πειράζων) is used for temptation, but it might not mean that for the reader here just yet. This is a familiar, everyday setback - of suddenly needing to cater for a large group - the group's extreme size doesn't make the situation categorically unrelatable, we can grasp it.
Therefore, it's not self-evidently faithless of Philip not to expect the Messiah to miraculously produce a huge quantity of food.
We might read this instead, initially, as a test of Philip's local knowledge, or (as I'll briefly contend) his willingness to pay. To the reader this might have resembled the early stages of a patronage relationship.
After a very recent and very brief conversation, which John relates to have been as brief as Jesus saying "follow me" = Ἀκολούθει μοι, Philip has joined a group following someone that he immediately professed to be "the One Moses wrote about in the Law, the One the prophets foretold." (John 1:45).
So we might have some questions about his judgement.
And that might make Philip's answer at John 6:5-7 reassuring and forthright: showing he isn't a fool, or vulnerable to financial exploitation by wandering quacks.
But neither is he rude. If you put him in an improbable circumstance and try to shake him down for some unreasonable sum of money ("how are we going to pay"), Philip knows how to push back. And he has the social skills to do it without embarrassing the other person. He hasn't said he won't chip in for some snacks, it's just let's everyone be clear about the money.
Perhaps we want to find in him someone who thinks he's being tested by a patron, and wanting to show himself to be a shrewd follower who's got some boundaries and self-worth and can work the whole gamut from leaping-to-action to cautiously-assessing. Someone whose loyalty is versatile. Our own cultural patronage systems have different protocols, but the fundamentals are the same the world over. It's a situation we can relate to.
But as we reflect on the text and return to it after having heard the Evangelion, we might find Philip in this short passage passing a greater test: demonstrating (to us. like it says, Jesus already knows) that his earlier haste came from faith and not from foolishness.
